# Array refreshing when redirecting route in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a React E-commerce Store WITHOUT react-shopping-cart/other packages. I essentially have an Item component rendering for each item within a category on separate category component pages (Tops component, Bottoms component, etc).

In order for me to push each Item to the Cart component, I have the following important snippets in the Item component:

```
addItem() {
        inCart.push(this.props.id);
        cartTotal += (this.props.price);
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

<Button variant="primary" onClick={this.addItem}>
                            Add to Cart
          </Button>

export let inCart = [];
```

Then within the Cart component, I render each added item using the following:

```
class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cartList: inCart,
            finalTotal: cartTotal.toFixed(2)
        }
    }

    removeItem(itemId, itemPrice) {
        var itemIndex = this.state.cartList.indexOf(itemId);
        var newList = inCart.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        var newTotal = (this.state.finalTotal - itemPrice).toFixed(2);
        this.setState({ cartList: newList, finalTotal: newTotal });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Page">
                <Navbar />
                <div className="Cart">
                    <div className="Cart-Items">
                        {Products.map((product) => {
                            if (inCart.includes(product.id)) {
                                return (
                                    <div className="Cart-CartItem">
                                        <CartItem
                                            id={product.id}
                                            name={product.name}
                                            img={product.img}
                                            description={product.description}
                                            price={product.price}
                                        />
                                        <div className="Cart-CartOptions">
                                            <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(product.id, product.price)}>Remove</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            }
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <div className="Cart-Total">
                        <h1>{this.state.finalTotal}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Cart;
```

Since the array is created and updated through the Item component, I don't understand why it's refreshing the array when adding items from other categories/components.

Any idea of what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to page refresh on page change due to Nav.Link in Bootstrap. To fix the issue, I change the Nav.Link in my Navbar to Link from React-router-dom.